# How to run a script using Django?

Tags: php, python, html, django, web

So I've conntected GMail API to my Django project. When I run quickstart.py alone in PyCharm it runs and works perfectly (that's the script that opens a new tab with GMail log in).

Great but now I have to give a user an opportunity to do the same. So I decided that I'll create a button and with pressing that button the quickstart.py will run and user will log in.
 [I tried that by creating an action.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANUZ7.jpg)
[Then I tried a usual 'a' tag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4yqT.png)
[And in both cases was error "Not found".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuJO4.jpg)
 Also I even tried to run an php where I execute .py script.Sounds crazy.

```
    <?php
echo exec('/quickstart.py');
?>
```

But the error is the same. I've also tried to play with url.py and write paths. I think I don't understand something. Please, explain.

So again and shortly: **Press button -> Run quickstart.py**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not to run **quickstart.py**, but create there some `function`, import your `from quickstart import your_function` into your `views.py` and call that `your_function` from `your_custom_view`.
Simplified logic like that:

```
from quickstart import your_function

def your_custom_view(request):
    button_was_pressed = request.GET.get("button")
    if button_was_pressed:
        your_function()
        return HttpResponse("Button pressed")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("No button pressed")
```

And make your `Button` work like a link (if you dont need a `POST` request), smth like:

```
<a href="{% url "your_custom_view_url" %}?button=True">Button</a>
```

**NOTE:** This is not working code, but simplified logic, with so short information that you gave.
**UPDATE 1**:
 
`settings.py`:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

`views.py`:

```
from your_project.settings import BASE_DIR

path_to_json = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, r'client_secret.json')
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(path_to_json, SCOPES)
```

Comment: OK, I've done next: 


1.https://ibb.co/mmv5Dn (That's the code from Google site and I've put it in one function) 


 2.https://ibb.co/nJQYzS


 3.https://ibb.co/ipDE67


 4.https://ibb.co/bGTQDn


And in result it can't find this file:
 https://ibb.co/eOC7R7

client_secret.json is connected with GMail API so I guess it entered that quickstart.py script but failed. I tried to create a path to .json file in urls.py but the IDE didn't even show it up in the list, like it's not there.

Comment: try **UPDATE 1**

Comment: https://ibb.co/heBepS - first step done

https://ibb.co/n41OG7 - I guess you wanted to write quickstart.py not views.py. So that 'os' was red and showed up "unresolved reference". I imported it : https://ibb.co/kGFm3n
It compiled without any error. Now when I click the button it shows: 
https://ibb.co/jOXoG7  
I searched and found that a guy was having the same trouble and it turned out that he wrote not 'client_secret.json' but 'client_secrets.json'. Well, in original code from Google it's without 's' except the case when you call "client.flow_from_clientsecrets".

Comment: What I've just tried: First I renamed .json file to an uncorrect name (by calling refactor-> rename). Then renamed it correct (also by refactor->rename) as it should be,as it's written by Google. I just wanted to make sure there no stupid problem with naming variables and functions.

Comment: Sure. It has only one but quiet long line of code with my client_id, project_id, auth_uri, token_uri, auth_provider_x509_cert_url, client_secret and redirect_uris. 

This .json file is downloaded from Google site after I turned on GMail API and set my project there.

I'm searching what could be the problem now but no ideas yet.

UPD: I'll try to reupload this .json file. Will reply soon.

Comment: Lol

Well, I downloaded it again, reuploaded to the project and nothing chaned...But then I moved it from "gappi" directory to "FastProject" 

https://ibb.co/fT9M3n

and when pressing the button happened this: 

https://ibb.co/g6ys9S

I'm searching right now what this could be

Comment: Alright, I figured out that with this path to .json file https://ibb.co/k8VuPS it searches it in FastProject. Why do I think so? Because when you put it with path 'client_secret.json' in gappi directory it says "client_secret.json not found" BUT when you drag .json file to FastProject or leave it in gappi but name the path 'gappi/client_secret.json' the error we like "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator." This means that it read .json file but something else went wrong. So now I try to figure out what is this "A server error occurred."

Comment: Good news. It really reads the .json file. This problem with "A server error occurred" was showing up because there was no credentials.json where it wanted to save that you have logged in. Now when I imported that file we have a message that the button was clicked and in console it shows info from my email. Now I just have to make a nice redirection to homepage. http://ibb.co/dW72B7 Thanks a lot for help ! Якщо буду якось в Запорізькій області, то з мене пиво. Дякую!

Comment: So it works? :) Nice! Sry I didn't amswer today - problems with internet, and from smartphone not so good to code. Кривий Ріг, він неправильно гелокацію визначив :D

Comment: Добре, буду якось в Кривому Розі, то повідомлю :)

Comment: I got another trouble here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50211733/gmail-api-messages-keyerror
Maybe, you can help

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what is going on there. May be try to look at the source code of that functions what u use, some times there are some additional comments written by developers.